# How does one load external code with a custom bootloader?

Tags: c, assembly, operating-system

I'm writing my own operating system, and so far I'm only really able to write it in assembly, because I don't really understand how I would set it up with multiple files/languages. I've written bootloaders with executable code in them before, but what I don't understand is **how to make the bootloader aware of other files outside of itself.** How would I be able to write a bootloader in assembly and then tell it to load, say, a kernel written in C in a different file? Do I have to bundle the .o files from the compilation of the kernel into the fdd image and tell the bootloader to load/execute them or is it more complicated than that?

Comment: You need to know what is a file system. You need to prepare for paged memory (protected mode), load FS drivers, create a loader that will properly load your kernel in memory and start it. After all, you need the kernel.

Comment: I know what a filesystem is. I'm planning simply to use FAT16 with a virtual fdd right now, because I'm just starting out.

Comment: I mean, the loader must know what it is. For a file to be defined, you need a filesystem.

Comment: Hmmm, looks like I'm gonna neeed to backtrack a bit then. I'm assuming that my code would automatically allocate memory in a way that conforms to the filesystem that the code is on, is that assumption right?

Comment: Memory allocation and filesystem are hardly related. When a computer (x86 or any other) boots, all memory is yours. You can do anything with all the physical memory without any allocations. Then you move to paged memory so that different pages get a protection, so you are not that free. Somewhere at this point you need to load a FS driver so that you actually can read and write files. How this is related to memory allocation, I don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

Since it looks like you're trying to get the hang of system bring up it might be worthwhile to take a look at some "smaller" embedded systems to get a feel for what goes on once power is applied/chip comes out of reset. Take a look at U-Boot here: http://www.denx.de/wiki/U-Boot

It is a very popular bootloader especially for embedded systems and can launch a variety of OS's. The mainline supports a ton of different configurations as well. I think it is relatively straight forward to follow what happens during power up if you are comfortable with C.

To answer your question more specifically for instance with U-Boot you can either build parameters into the u-boot image as to where you are going to load your code, it can read where you image file is stored from a configuration file on powerup, u-boot can load a configuration automatically from your network somewhere, you can even tell u-boot where and what to load from its command line interface. Take a look and see if you have any further questions.